# dyld: Library not loaded: error when running on iphone device

Tags: ios, xcode

Recently I upgrade xcode to 8.0. Since I am using swift2 when I load my previous project xcode will prompt a dialog to migrate my current code to swift2.3. After doing this, my project failed to run on the iphone device. It works fine on simulator. Below is the error I got when running on a device.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/29C6F6B8-4CFB-4D1D-864E-45FF6AB13971/cooltoo_go2nurse_ios.app/cooltoo_go2nurse_ios
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/29C6F6B8-4CFB-4D1D-864E-45FF6AB13971/cooltoo_go2nurse_ios.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/29C6F6B8-4CFB-4D1D-864E-45FF6AB13971/cooltoo_go2nurse_ios.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
```

I have searched the similar error and tried below suggestions but none of them solve my problem.

1. In build phase, I added "Copy Files" phase then add Alamofire.framework with Frameworks as the destination, then checked 'Code Sign Copy'.
2. Set $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks on Runpath Search Paths in Build Settings.
3. In General tab, add Alamofire.framework in Embedded Binaries.

Below is my Podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!


target 'cooltoo_go2nurse_ios' do
    pod 'IQKeyboardManager', '4.0.5'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', '4.0.5'
    pod 'MJRefresh'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.2'
    pod 'Alamofire', '3.5.0'
    pod 'CryptoSwift', :git => "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift", :branch => "swift2"
    pod 'Pingpp', '~> 2.1.4'
    use_frameworks!
end


target 'cooltoo_go2nurse_iosTests' do


end


target 'cooltoo_go2nurse_iosUITests' do


end


post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
        end
    end
end
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I second this. Here is what I know so far. There seems to be a signing issue. My issue with this was preceded by a ridiculously slow COPY PODS script, looking at the console I was seeing signing errors all over the place. I logged into a fresh account on my computer and was able to get things running right again. Once I logged back into my original account everything came to a screeching halt. I've tried blasting my keychain, re-installing everything imaginable, and nothing is working thus far. I'm on the 8.1 GM, which is when this all started.

--- Edit 10/26/16

I determined that this was a corruption of my signing certificates in combination with something wrong with the keychain, or changes to the keychain being registered with the system. In order to fix this I did a clean install of macOS and restored my files through iCloud rather than from a time machine backup.

I still don't know what caused it but I do know that even with my keychain completely deleted and NO certificates on my computer that Xcode was installing and trying to run on the device. Ultimately the error means that the code is not properly signed so it won't allow the library to be copied and run.